# get an entry type from api qyert

Tags: wiki, geo, mediawiki-api

i'm doing geosearch in wiki-api which will supposed to find me all the entries in a certain radius from  some coordinates.

[Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=100&gscoord=40.748525%7C-73.985696&gslimit=500&format=xml).

in need (in addition to the result) that it will return me the type of the entry
or the abstract of the entry.

thanks

Comment: How are you doing this?  Is there some programming language involved?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Add [&gsprop=type](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=100&gscoord=40.748525%7C-73.985696&gslimit=500&gsprop=type&format=xml) to your query.